# How to populate dynamic content in standard email template using AMPscript (when multi-org is enabled)

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, multi-org

If I create dynamic content in standard email template, it will use personalization strings to retrieve Salesforce fields from profile attributes and display dynamically whenever email is sent to subscribers

Now I am trying figure out if Multi-org is enabled in the Account, personalization strings will not work, in that case how it will populate Salesforce fields in the Standard email template.

Will personalization strings functionality breaks?? if it breaks how can I handle this particular situation using AMPscript

Comment: The docs are poor for multi-org and I'm sympathetic to your problem... Once enabled, you can't disable multi-org, you know there are lots of limitations and the wording of the documentation's too vague to come to any informed judgment on whether to use it or not. I'd defer to those with hands-on experience on what "standard fields work" means. My assumption at the moment is you'll need to use AMPScript's "RetrieveSalesforceObjects" function to personalise content and Dynamic Content blocks won't work for anything that isn't a "Standard Field". Raise a case as the docs are no good. And share.

Comment: Developer accounts and self enabling business rules would be a good proxy for worthwhile documentation. My two cents.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMcLeod got update from salesforce, Posted Answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got update from Support: Multi-org enable doesn't break personalization strings(custom fields) in standard email template as we mapped the MC fields to SF fields in profile management

Answer (score -1):

You can connect to multiple orgs in two ways: 
 
1. one Marketing Cloud business unit to one Sales or Service Cloud org 
2. many Marketing Cloud business units to one Sales or Service Cloud org 

 Refer [this link](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/features/multi_org_account_configuration/multi_org_account_and_user_configuration/) for multi org details.

In any case, the salesforce ids will be unique and you should be able to create profile attributes 
Alternatively, you can also use AMP Script function CreateSalesforceObject to retrieve account information from sales org based on email address from sendable data extension and then use it in Emails for dynamic content/personalisation.

 Refer [this link](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/createsalesforceobject/) for AMPScript details.